# Jquery not changing input text after autocomplete

Tags: jquery

my jquery is having a little issue. 
I'm trying to make a Start and Finish time function. I would like it to check that the finish time is greater or equal than the start time and if it is change it to +1 hour of the value of start.

It all works apart from `$('#finish').val(result);`

For some reason it does not change the value. Any ideas?

```
$( "#finish" ).autocomplete(
            {
                delay: 0,
                source: time_values,
                select: function(event, ui) 
                {
                    var res = ui.item.value;
                    var start = $( "#start" ).val();

                    if(res <= start)
                    {
                        alert('Finish time cannot be less than Start time');
                        var hour = '1.00';
                        var result =  +start + +hour;

                        $('#finish').val(result);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RTp2d/1/ thats my attempt at a jsFiddle, although I cant for the life of get it to work!

Comment: It looks like it works: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/RTp2d/2/ (I just added jQuery and jQuery UI)

Comment: ahh didnt know you had to do that. That was my first jsFiddle experience

Comment: So then what part of the fiddle isn't working?

Comment: Back to it. I want it so the #finish value is not less than or equal to #start value. So 7.30 - 8.30 is fine. 7.30 - 5.30 is not. I was trying to make it that once it notices this, #finish is automatically changed to +1 hour of #start. Does that make sense?

Comment: It seems like you're checking after the start value is selected. Shouldn't the check come when the finish value is selected instead?

Comment: The check does seem to work tho. Enter 6.30 in start and 5.30 in finish. It does the alert and if I put alert(result) the correct value is displayed. Its just updating the value that doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to convert the string to another type before comparison,

try

```
var res = parseFloat(ui.item.value);
 var start = parseFloat($( "#start" ).val());
```